# Use Laravel Hashes in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, hash, laravel

I want to use the hashes from a database for a Code Igniter admin panel. The hashes are created trough Laravel's Hash::make();

Is there any option I can use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses the PHP function [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to calculate BCrypt hashes for passwords, and [`password_verify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to compare them. You can use the PHP functions directly in CodeIgniter.

For PHP versions before 5.5 there exists a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).

Comment: CodeIgniter 3 have these compatibility functions built-in

Comment: Thnx Martin!

@ahmad, might be totally oftopic, but AFAIK Code Igniter halted at version 2.14. Where is 3?

Comment: version 3 is still in development, And will be out soon, for the time being if you want to use it you can download it off github